# Python - parsing xml with escaped brackets

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse some xml but it contains some escaped characters. Is there an easier way to do this ?

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Group id="RHEL-07-010010">
    <title>SRG-OS-000257-GPOS-00098</title>
    <description>&lt;GroupDescription&gt;&lt;/GroupDescription&gt;    </description>
    <Rule id="RHEL-07-010010_rule" severity="high" weight="10.0">
      <version>RHEL-07-010010</version>
      <title>The file permissions, ownership, and group membership of system files and commands must match the vendor values.</title>
      <description>&lt;VulnDiscussion&gt;Discretionary access control is weakened if a user or group has access permissions to system files and directories greater than the default.

Satisfies: SRG-OS-000257-GPOS-00098, SRG-OS-000278 GPOS-00108&lt;/VulnDiscussion&gt;
   </Rule>
 </Group>
```

I am trying to pull out the group id, rule severity, title and VulnDiscussion which is contained in the description tag. I can get everything but the VulnDiscussion because it contains escaped characters > and <

Here is my code :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import HTMLParser


tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()


for findings in root.iter('Group'):
    print findings.get('id')
    rule = findings.find('Rule')
    print rule.get('severity')
    print rule.find('title').text
    description = rule.find('description')

   # my attempt at unescaping the description tag to parse the VulnDiscussion
   embeddedHtml = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
   unescapedXML = embeddedHtml.unescape(description)
   newtree = ET.fromstring(unescapedXML) 
   print newtree.get(VulnDiscussion).text
```

Crashes with :

```
 newtree = ET.fromstring(unescapedXML)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions /2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1300, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1640, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not Element
```

Comment: Did the answer I posted solve your question or were you looking for something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) instead of the standard library's `xml`, it's a bit more robust and functional. It even unescapes the escaped symbols in the text automatically. Using [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) makes your life easier here, too.

```
from lxml import etree as ET

xml = ET.XML(b"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Group id="RHEL-07-010010">
    <title>SRG-OS-000257-GPOS-00098</title>
    <description>&lt;GroupDescription&gt;&lt;/GroupDescription&gt;    </description>
    <Rule id="RHEL-07-010010_rule" severity="high" weight="10.0">
      <version>RHEL-07-010010</version>
      <title>The file permissions, ownership, and group membership of system files and commands must match the vendor values.</title>
      <description>&lt;VulnDiscussion&gt;Discretionary access control is weakened if a user or group has access permissions to system files and directories greater than the default.

Satisfies: SRG-OS-000257-GPOS-00098, SRG-OS-000278 GPOS-00108&lt;/VulnDiscussion&gt;
      </description>
   </Rule>
 </Group>""")

for description in xml.xpath('//description/text()'):
    vulnDiscussion = next(iter(ET.XML(description).xpath('/VulnDiscussion/text()')), None)
    print(vulnDiscussion)
```

The above code produces

```
None
Discretionary access control is weakened if a user or group has access permissions to system files and directories greater than the default.

Satisfies: SRG-OS-000257-GPOS-00098, SRG-OS-000278 GPOS-00108
```

Comment: I am new to python and am trying to test your answer but it produces an error. There is one diference, however I am loading the xml from a file, here is the code: ` from lxml import etree as ET

xml = ET.parse("test.xml")

for description in xml.path('//description/text()'):
 print(description) `   I receive the error : for description in xml.path('//description/text()'):
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'path'

Comment: That looks like a typo to me. The method name should be `xpath` rather than `path`.

Comment: so the goal was to get the VulnDescription tag contents, when I try for description in xml.xpath('//VulnDiscussion/text()'): print description I get nothing ?

Comment: You need to parse the contents of <description> a second time to get the contents of <VulnDiscussion>. I edited my answer to do that as well.

Comment: The `next(iter(...), None)` is there just to extract the value we want from a list (with only one element), btw.

Comment: I am getting this now:  vulnDiscussion = next(iter(ET.XML(description).xpath('//VulnDiscussion/text()')), None)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3192, in lxml.etree.XML (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:78763)
 .....
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 3, column 79   If I just put xml.xpath('//description/text()') I get all the description tag and no error but when I try your latest code to get the VulnDiscussion it gives the above error.

Comment: Ok, that means there is some content which is outside the XML tags in the descrption content. It's getting outside the scope of this question. You should create a separate one for that.